# IllegalArgumentException When trying to use @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I am trying to *stylize* the *TextInputLayout* with an outline. But when I try to use `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox` in style attribute my app crashes with this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

## Here is the TextInputLayout theme I want to use OutlinedBox

### It was working fine but suddenly this error appeared during development

```
<style name="LoginTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke</item>

</style>
```

## Global App Theme

```
<!-- Base application No Action bar theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/opensans_regular</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Post your app theme. You have to use a Theme.MaterialComponents

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response I have added theme

Comment: It is the style of the TextInputLayout. It is not the theme used by your app.

Comment: I want to give outlinedbox style to TextInputLayout and app crashes if use these, if I use Theme.MaterialComponents there is no way of giving it OutlinedBox style

Comment: Ok it is clear. I am asking something different. What is the global app theme?

Comment: I have added the Global App Theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported in the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)

You have to [change the app theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) to a Material Components Theme like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
   <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

Comment: Thank You so much I got it. I have to change theme of main app.

Comment: please have a look at this issue @Gabriele https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850751/switching-to-material-theme-from-app-compact-shows-white-blank-labels-buttons