# switching to Theme.MaterialComponents from Theme.AppCompat shows white blank labels & buttons

Tags: android-layout, material-ui, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I was  using [Material](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) design `1.1.0`

For Tabs with `Viewpager2` . I updated it to `'1.2.0-alpha05'` [Material](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) library version it was working fine for single module but was crashing for another module where I've developed my custom material designed **TextInputLayout**. I changed theme from `'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` and crash fixed. After fixing crash and upgrading theme it is showing me white **floating label , buttons , indiators** etc anyone please guide me where am I doing wrong.?

**GITHUb Issue Ticket Link :**
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1207

[TextInputLayout](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md#theming-text-fields)

> Style.xml (Old File)

@color/white

        
        @color/colorPrimary_New

        
        @color/a465661

old file had conflict with material while using AppCompact with `parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"` after updating to 1.2.0-alpha05 it was resolved but style background is not working now

> Library

```
materialVersion = '1.2.0-alpha05'

 "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
```

> .XML (Design)

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        style="@style/contentInputLayoutStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8dp"
        app:errorEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/errorTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:hint="@string/EnterMobileNumber">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textDirection="anyRtl"
            tools:text="0335510023"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/inputFieldPadding_36dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/inputFieldPadding_36dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> Style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar" >
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/green</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/a465661</item>
        </style>

 <style name="contentInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/border_stroke_grey</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/error_label</item>
        <item name="counterOverflowTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance
        </item>
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/text_label</item>
    </style>

 <style name="text_label" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_heading_12sp</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="text_label_green" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_heading_12sp</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/green_field</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green_field</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/green_field</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance" parent="text_label">
        <!-- Floating label appearance here -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/label_title_black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_heading_12sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/label_title_black</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/label_title_black</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/label_title_black</item>

    </style>

  <style name="material_edit_text" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:paddingStart">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="error_label" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    </style>

  <style name="BtnCustomStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_confirm_selector</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">46dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:foreground">android:attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    </style>
```

> Style(v27).xml **(deleted file)**

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary_New</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/a465661</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">never</item>
    </style>
```

**Update**

```
"Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
```

this line was causing crash while using appCompact Theme.

Read topic on [material design](https://medium.com/over-engineering/setting-up-a-material-components-theme-for-android-fbf7774da739) UI update. According to this document I've to add few attributes that are below!

```
    <!-- New MaterialComponents attributes. -->

    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/whitee</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/colorPrimary_New</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/a465661</item>-->
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/a465661</item>-->
    <item name="colorOnBackground">#212121</item>-->
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorError">#F44336</item>-->
    <item name="colorOnError">#FFFFFF</item>
```

but , I tried changing color for TextInputLayout its working fine but for button its not. anyone please guide me how to handle this with new material design.?

[image: ImageSample]

**update :**

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
```

add the above-mentioned theme to the widget and it will solve your issue.for example.

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_background"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_background"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"

        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationActive"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationInactive" />
```

Comment: i think you need to view the theme accent colour of both libraries or by changing their colour if anyone have white colour turn them into red you may got clue there.

Comment: Which style are you using for buttons?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti updated question style named BtnCustomStyle using for buttons.

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi Your style for the button should extend the Widget.MaterialComponents.Button

Comment: and what about white effect on edittext cursor , floating label & buttons .? @GabrieleMariotti